# How to write a maven plugin which can output the dependencies in a JSON format?

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I want to write a plugin which can output the dependencies of a project into a custom JSON format file, so I can parse it easily in other systems (a custom website to search the dependencies of our project).

Maven itself has an official `maven-dependency-plugin` which can output the dependencies as a plain text tree. Which contains all the information I need, but I'm not sure if I can invoke it to get the information?

Or is there any other way to make it possible?

Comment: First of all. Maven has no built-in plugins. The maven-dependency-plugin is a separated plugin as any other plugin...You can take a look into the code of the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/source-repository.html). The other question is why you need to get the dependencies in other systems? And just for curiosity: What kind of other systems?

Comment: If you like to search for dependencies you should take a deep look into Nexus (REST API) and the maven-indexer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the depends-maven-plugin to get the data as properties.
2. Use antrun or exec to transform into the json format you need.

> ```
> <plugin>
>    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.tooling</groupId>
>       <artifactId>depends-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>       <executions>
>         <execution>
>           <id>generate-depends-file</id>
>           <goals>
>             <goal>generate-depends-file</goal>
>           </goals>
>         </execution>
>       </executions>
>     </plugin>
> ```